# List population based on If-else condition

Tags: apex, list

```
if (Option.equalsIgnoreCase('A')) {
List<AggregateResult> List1 = [select SUM(Field1__c), SUM(Field2__c),  from CustomObject__c  where Month__c = :currentMonth AND Year__c =:currentYear ];
}
else
{
List<AggregateResult> List1 = [select SUM(Field1__c), SUM(Field2__c),  from CustomObject__c  where Quarter__c = :currentQuarter AND Year__c =:currentYear ];
}
```

On adding this , it is throwing an error - Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: List1

What am I doing wrong in syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apex variables are block level scoped which mean if its declared within a block,you can use it only within that block only.

With that said,it looks like you want to use it after the block(in your case if/else),then declare the collection variable `List1` before the block.
Like this:

```
List<AggregateResult> List1;
if (Option.equalsIgnoreCase('A')) {
    List1 = [select SUM(Field1__c), SUM(Field2__c),  from CustomObject__c  where Month__c = :currentMonth AND Year__c =:currentYear ];
}
else
{
    List1 = [select SUM(Field1__c), SUM(Field2__c),  from CustomObject__c  where Quarter__c = :currentQuarter AND Year__c =:currentYear ];
}
```